# How to update to WordPress 3.6 and not lose my website's design

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm using WordPress 3.5 now, but I want to upgrade to WordPress 3.6. How I can do this? 
And how can I customize my posts, comments types?

Answer (score 4):

Upgrading to a new version of Wordpress only changes the core files and does not touch any other files such as themes and plug-ins. You might want to check whether your plug-ins are compatible with 3.6. Base themes (such as the newly introduced 2013) will only install fresh together with a major update but will not automatically update with a Wordpress update. Theme updates are seperate.

Normally, your theme should work fine in WP 3.6. If you are really worried, make sure to have a back-up of all your content.